# Why is Mono's Evaluator.Evaluate() causing a FileLoadException - AssemblyResolveEvent handlers cannot return Assemblies loaded for reflection only?

Tags: c#, mono, assembly-resolution

I have the following code:

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        var reportPrinter = new ConsoleReportPrinter();
        var compilerSettings = new CompilerSettings();
        var compilerContext = new CompilerContext(compilerSettings, reportPrinter);

        var evaluator = new Evaluator(compilerContext);

        var loadedBefore = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Assembly[] loadedAfter;
        try
        {
            var result = evaluator.Evaluate("1+2");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loadedAfter = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This code works fine in a toy standalone project, but once I put it into my main project, the evaluator.Evaluate() calls a `FileLoadException - AssemblyResolveEvent handlers cannot return Assemblies loaded for reflection only.`.

Unfortunately I have very little idea what is causing this, and not being very familiar with the .NET internals I have even less of an idea of how to go about diagnosing this.

My main project does have a lot of dependencies that use meta-programming of some form (NHibernate, ActiPro Syntax Editor, DevExpress, Antlr). The project itself also uses Microsoft's CodeDOM to compile and execute user scripts (in the same AppDomain - and yes I am aware of issues). And I did get the same exception in the past - it was fixed by scrubbing my library files and copying them from a fellow developer again. We never got to the bottom of that. I'm not sure if that points to some sort of versioning mismatch between dependencies?

Anyway, the `loadedBefore` variable at the time of the exception throw is identical to `loadedAfter`. It contains the following:

```
{mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{vshost, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
{WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
{System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
{DevExpress.Utils.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraBars.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraEditors.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.Data.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
{System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821}
{System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
{NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4}
{FluentNHibernate, Version=1.1.0.685, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880}
{Iesi.Collections, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4}
{System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{DevExpress.XtraGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
{DevExpress.XtraCharts.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4}
{System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139}
{System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{DevExpress.Spreadsheet.v14.1.Core, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
{Mono.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756}
{DevExpress.PivotGrid.v14.1.Core, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{Castle.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc}
{OpenTK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bad199fe84eb3df4}
{ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Addons.DotNet.Net20, Version=4.0.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21a821480e210563}
{WW.Cad, Version=4.0.35.116, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87d16b8f7b531b65}
{WW, Version=4.0.35.116, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87d16b8f7b531b65}
{System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36ff2196ab5654b9}
{ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Net20, Version=4.0.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21a821480e210563}
{System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
{ActiproSoftware.WinUICore.Net20, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1eba893a2bc55de5}
{DevExpress.XtraLayout.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a}
{System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
{Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
{UIAutomationClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
{Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
{Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
```

In addition I added the following ot the start of my Main method:

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        var assemblyLoadedEventLog = "";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, a) => { assemblyLoadedEventLog += DateTime.Now + " " + a.LoadedAssembly.ToString() + Environment.NewLine; };      

        ...
```

The assemblyLoadedEventLog then contains:

```
10/10/2014 4:44:51 PM log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821 False
10/10/2014 4:44:51 PM System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 False
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
10/10/2014 4:44:51 PM NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4 False
10/10/2014 4:44:51 PM FluentNHibernate, Version=1.1.0.685, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM Iesi.Collections, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.XtraGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.XtraCharts.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.Spreadsheet.v14.1.Core, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
[INTERNAL LIBRARY REDACTED]
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM Mono.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM DevExpress.PivotGrid.v14.1.Core, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM Castle.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM OpenTK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bad199fe84eb3df4 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Addons.DotNet.Net20, Version=4.0.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21a821480e210563 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM WW.Cad, Version=4.0.35.116, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87d16b8f7b531b65 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM WW, Version=4.0.35.116, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87d16b8f7b531b65 False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a False
10/10/2014 4:44:52 PM System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 False
10/10/2014 4:44:53 PM ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36ff2196ab5654b9 False
10/10/2014 4:44:53 PM ActiproSoftware.SyntaxEditor.Net20, Version=4.0.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21a821480e210563 False
10/10/2014 4:44:54 PM ActiproSoftware.WinUICore.Net20, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1eba893a2bc55de5 False
10/10/2014 4:44:54 PM System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 False
10/10/2014 4:44:54 PM DevExpress.XtraLayout.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:55 PM DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:56 PM DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a False
10/10/2014 4:44:57 PM System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a False
10/10/2014 4:44:57 PM Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null False
10/10/2014 4:44:59 PM UIAutomationClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 False
10/10/2014 4:45:02 PM Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 False
10/10/2014 4:45:02 PM Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 False
10/10/2014 4:45:13 PM System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 True
```

The puzzling thing (for me) is the bottom entry - why on earth is the System assembly being loaded in Reflection Only context here? Is this some cross-appdomain confounding?